# Update related entities

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling to find a simple way to update DB with an object graph with all the related entites.
Let's assume that we have an Article entity and Category entity with many-to-many relation (additional ArticleCategory entity)

I would like to update an entity (Article) with new set of categories - some may be added, some may be deleted

I thought it would be possible to do something like this:

```
var newCategoriesIds = new List<int>{1,2,3};

var article = article entity fetched from db

article.Categories = newCategoriesIds.Select(c=> new ArticleCategory(){
Id = c
})

dbContext.Update(article);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't as I initially thought. It tries to add (again) a row to ArticleCategory entity with the same values so it leads to primary key violation.
If there are completely different categories in input collection - the old ones aren't deleted and the new ones are added.

Am I missing something? Is this some configuration issue or rather I should do the update in a different manner?

Comment: Load object from database with all required collections, then update returned objects properties (no `Update` call is needed). Then `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Does 'SaveChanges()' in each step solve your problem?